# Could anyone please spot the error in this java code of mine

Tags: java

```
{      
       PrintHeaderLine();

       System.out.format("%-15s %-55s %15s %n", "SL NO", "PRODUCT", "COST");

       PrintHeaderLine();

      for(int x=0;x<k;x++)
      {
          totalcash=totalcash+amount[x];
          System.out.format("%-15s %-55s %15s %n", (x+1), itemsbought[x], "$"+ amount[x]);
      }      
      if(totalcash>=500&&totalcash<1000)
      {
          totalcash=totalcash*(95/100);
        }
      else if(totalcash>=1000&&totalcash<3000)
      {
      totalcash=totalcash*(90/100);
    }
      else if(totalcash>=3000)
      {
      totalcash=totalcash*(85/100);

    }
    else 
      totalcash=totalcash+0;
      PrintHeaderLine();     

      System.out.format("%-15s %71s %n", "GRAND TOTAL ", "$" + totalcash);
```

(I KEEP ON GETTING THE OUTPUT AS 0) IK THERES NOTHING WRONG WITH MY CODE BEFORE ONLY THIS PROBLEM. COULD SOMEONE TELL ME WHERE IM GOING WRONG

Comment: Use a debugger. Also, integer division.

Comment: `"THERES NOTHING WRONG WITH MY CODE"` - Kind of a bold statement, given that you're not able to debug it or to prove that it does what you expect it to do.

Comment: I used double.. totalcash is a static double variable declared on top.. :/no syntax errors.. I just get the wrong output it always prints as 0

Comment: @David ive tried executing the program without the discount statements which ive typed above and it works perfectly fine ;/ so yh.... I add these statements and my output is always  0

Answer (score 1):

In your if/if else statements you're multiplying your totalcash variable by an integer value of 0. When you divide an integer (95) by another integer (100) you get integer division as a result, which equates to an integer value of 0.

Try:

```
if(totalcash>=500&&totalcash<1000)
{
    totalcash=totalcash*((double)95/100);
}
else if(totalcash>=1000&&totalcash<3000)
{
    totalcash=totalcash*((double)90/100);
}
else if(totalcash>=3000)
{
    totalcash=totalcash*((double)85/100);
}
else 
     totalcash=totalcash+0;
```

Answer (score 1):

- 95/100 = 0
- 90/100 = 0
- 85/100 = 0

Given that all of these equal 0, then:

- totalcash * 0 = 0

Therefore:

- totalcash = 0

If you want to use doubles, you need to use doubles in the math expressions as well.  Currently the above values are all integers.  So instead of this:

```
95/100
```

Do this:

```
95.0/100.0
```